# Popover with vue.js and bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to add popovers from bootstrap 4 into my vue.js app. I could probably use something like `https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-popperjs`, but I'd like to make it work old way, without using additional libraries (just so I could figure out the principle on how to do that)

I have installed `Popper.js` with `npm install --save popper`

In my `webpack.config.js` I also have:

```
 plugins: [
        new WebpackNotifierPlugin(),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            _: 'lodash',
            $: 'jquery',
            jquery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            popper: 'popper'
        })
    ],
```

Then I'm tring to build a vue component:

```
<template>
   ....
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" title="" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom"  data-original-title="Connection String" aria-describedby="popover253231">
                                        Click to show 
                                    </button>
   ....
</template>
<script>
    const _ = require("lodash");
    const $ = require("jquery");
    // This doesn't work
    //const poppper = require("popper");
     var d = {
        data() {
           ...
        },
        created: function() {
           // Load data with $http module
        },
        updated: function() {
            $(function () {
                $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
            })
        },
    };

    export default d;
</script>
```

The button will appear only after load, because it has a parent element that has `v-for` binding on the data loaded with ajax.

I don't know how to require `popper`, so the line `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()` resolves (it cannot find function `popover()`)

Also the line `const popper = require("poppper")` doesn't work either with the error `Module parse failed: 'return' outside of function`. My guess is that I can't load `popper` with `require`, because it is not built for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some struggling and trying completely random ideas, I had the one that worked. Turns out the problem was that I was using `bootstrap` that is installed into `ASP.NET MVC` as a bundle (so it added it as `<script src='..'/>` to the page).
So after I:

1. `npm install --save bootstrap`
2. Added `bootstrap: 'bootstrap'` to `ProvidePlugin` definition in `webpack.config.js`
3. Added `require("bootstrap")` into my vue file

It started to work. I didn't even have to `require 'popper'` for some reason - probably because `bootstrap` already contains it?

Though I am still not sure whether this is a proper way to solve the problem

Comment: Since `popper.js` is a dependency for `bootstrap.js` it was probably installed when you installed Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Using Vuejs Directive

```
const bsPopover = (el, binding) => {

const p = []

if (binding.modifiers.focus) p.push('focus')
if (binding.modifiers.hover) p.push('hover')
if (binding.modifiers.click) p.push('click')
if (!p.length) p.push('hover')

$(el).popover({
    animation: false,
    placement: binding.arg || 'top',
    trigger: p.join(' '),
    html: !!binding.modifiers.html,
    content: binding.value,
});}

Vue.directive('tooltip', {
bind: bsTooltip,
update: bsTooltip,
unbind (el) { $(el).tooltip('dispose') }});
```